# Yii: How to set up roles in yii-user extensions?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I installed the `yii user extension` and now i am wandering how i can add an extra role. I added a new column in the User db table and edited the `UserModule` like this:

```
public static function isEmployee() {
        if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            return false;
        else {
            if (!isset(self::$_employee)) {
                            //check to see what kind of user we got and include admin for all 
                if(self::user()->type)
                    self::$_employee = true;
                else
                    self::$_employee = false;   
            }
            return self::$_employee;
        }
    }
```

and then when i try calling this in the rest of my site it dose not seem to work

```
'visible' => Yii::app()->user->isEmployee()
```

What i am doing wrong or what would be the best way to add an extra role that i can call on the site as above.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user-management/ ? It offers a decent RBAC, I've used it in production before. Easy to setup and use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which extension exactly you installed - but you confused it with the `user` component. The user component is what you can access through `Yii::app()->user`. It's a `CWebUser` object by default. You can create your custom `class WebUser extends CWebUser` in the `components/` directory. You would configure this as `user` component in your `main.php` config file.

```
'components' => array(
    'user' => 'WebUser',
),
```

Then you move your `isEmployee()` method into that class. As you didn't provide any details on which extension you used, i can not really help you how to get that role check right. But i wonder if you shouldn't rather use a RBAC based solution. It allows you to create Roles and assign them to users. There are also several extensions that help you to manage roles and users.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply , this is the extension i used http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/ let me know if you know how to add a role to this , thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Yii User](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/) is not meant for adding roles to users, it only handles user account management.

You may install an additional extension like rights, auth or srbac (see [list](http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/?category=1&sort=rating.desc)) which provides a web-interface for this task.